# How to define ANTLR Parser Rule for concatenated tokens/

Tags: antlr4

I need to match a token that can be combined from two parts:
"string" +  any number; e.g. string64, string128, etc.

In the lexer rules  I have

```
STRING: S T R I N G;
NUMERIC_LITERAL:
    ((DIGIT+ ('.' DIGIT*)?) | ('.' DIGIT+)) (E [-+]? DIGIT+)?
    | '0x' HEX_DIGIT+;
```

In the parser, I defined

```
type_id_string: STRING NUMERIC_LITERAL;
```

However, the parser doesn't not match and stop at expecting STRING token

How do I tell the parser that token has two parts?

BR

Comment: You need to provide a complete grammar and input. This grammar, completed from the rules you provide, works just fine. Also, you should use `option { caseInsensitive=true; }` and `STRING: 'string';` instead of the pre-version-4.10 way. `grammar F;
options { caseInsensitive = true; }
file_ : type_id_string* EOF;
type_id_string: STRING NUMERIC_LITERAL;
STRING: 'string';
NUMERIC_LITERAL: ((DIGIT+ ('.' DIGIT*)?) | ('.' DIGIT+)) (E [-+]? DIGIT+)? | '0x' HEX_DIGIT+;
fragment DIGIT : [0-9];
fragment HEX_DIGIT : [0-9a-f];
fragment E : 'e';
WS : [ \r\n\t] + -> channel(HIDDEN) ;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have some "identifier" rule like this:

```
ID
 : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z0-9_]*
 ;
```

which will cause input like `string64` to be tokenized as an `ID` token and *not* as a `STRING` and `NUMERIC_LITERAL` tokens.

Also trying to match these sort of things in a parser rule like:

```
type_id_string: STRING NUMERIC_LITERAL;
```

will go wrong when you're discarding white spaces in the lexer. If the input would then be `"string 64"` (`string` + space + `64`) it could possible be matched by `type_id_string`, which is probably not what you want.

Either do:

```
type_id_string
 : ID
 ;
```

or define these tokens in the lexer:

```
type_id_string
 : ID
 ;

// Important to match this before the `ID` rule!
TYPE_ID_STRING
 : [a-zA-Z] [0-9]+
 ;

ID
 : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z0-9_]*
 ;
```

However, when doing that, input like `fubar1` will also become a `TYPE_ID_STRING` and not an `ID`!

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. I ended up reordering the rules so the type_id_string will proceed  the ID(great guess BTW)